# Solution for php ZipArchieve Error code 9

Tags: php

I am trying to make zip with help of the below code. It works fine in my localhost. But when I transfer it to DirectAdmin server, It returns error code 9 `ZipArchive::ER_NOENT        : return 'N No such file';`

I don't know how to fix it to create zip

```
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/' );
$dest = ABSPATH.'zip_file_name.zip';
$file = ABSPATH.'test.php';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
  $res = $zip->open($dest, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);
  if ($res === TRUE) {
      echo 'ok';
      $zip->addFile($file, $file);
      $zip->close();
  } else {
      echo 'failed, code:' . $res;
  }
```

Comment: Make sure that the web server have have write access in that folder.

Comment: i have another function in the same directory, where it uploads files into it. and the files are zipped in the parent directory with this fucntion. But its not working even within the directory and outside directory

Comment: Does the zip file "zip_file_name.zip" already exists? If not you can create it with: 
the flag ZipArchive::CREATE
$zip->open($dest, ZipArchive::CREATE|ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);

Comment: @SteffenMächtel it works in localhost, even the file not exist. But the only problem with server.  even there is no other error. Permissions also set to 777.  Is there anyway to check it error catch methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tested your script on localhost (Windows). I get the error message "failed, code:9".

@see http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php and search for "ZipArchive::ER_NOENT".

I think you need to create the zip file.

When i add **ZipArchive::CREATE** it works (Output "ok"):

```
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/' );
$dest = ABSPATH.'zip_file_name.zip';
$file = ABSPATH.'test.php';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
  $res = $zip->open($dest, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);
  if ($res === TRUE) {
      echo 'ok';
      $zip->addFile($file, $file);
      $zip->close();
  } else {
      echo 'failed, code:' . $res;
  }
```

**-- UPDATE --**

The file test.php inside zip_file_name.zip has the full windows path.  There is a directory "C:" inside the the zip file on root level (Windows environment). Is this correct?

In case you dont want absolute path you can use relative path:

```
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/' );
$dest = ABSPATH.'zip_file_name.zip';
$relativeFile = 'test.php';
$absoluteFile = ABSPATH.$relativeFile;
$zip = new ZipArchive;
  $res = $zip->open($dest, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);
  if ($res === TRUE) {
      echo 'ok';
      $zip->addFile($absoluteFile, $relativeFile);
      $zip->close();
  } else {
      echo 'failed, code:' . $res;
  }
```

Comment: A small mistake made me to wait for few days. Thank you for fixing it.

Comment: Oddly I came across this issue when going from php5 to php7... in php5 all I had was `ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE` and everything worked fine. But until I changed it to `ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE` ... would it also work fine in php7.

Comment: I would like to take the chance to welcome people coming here after upgrading to PHP 7 :-)